# calculating the effect of a point-spread function in the frequency domain

Tags: matrices, signal-processing, fourier-transform, image-processing

If my point spread function looks like:

h(x) = 1, |x| <= W (where W is a positive integer)
       0, |x| > W

then i want to measure how it would effect the frequency content of some function f(x), would a correct approach be to calculate its mtf and then show that it would result in a blurring effect? any help is much appreciated

Comment: $1_{f \in [-w,w]}$ is the Fourier transform of $\frac{\sin(\pi w x)}{\pi x}$ therefore multiplication by $1_{f \in [-w,w]}$ in Fourier domain is the same as convolution by $\frac{\sin(\pi x w)}{\pi x}$ in time domain. In dimension $2$ it works the same way with  $\frac{\sin(\pi x w)}{\pi x} \frac{\sin(\pi  w y )}{\pi y}$

Comment: @reuns would you mind showing the calcultion for how you got the fourier transform stated above? the rest of it i understands, since its that fourier transform in the frequency domain in the spatial domain it would just be that value multiplied by the input correct?